# Angular js show/hide only working in page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS.
Here i want to display some html while switching from one controller to another.
This is my HomeController

```html
function HomeController($scope) {
 alert("hi");
 $scope.myValue = true;
}
```

This is my MainController.
Initially it is false in my MainController.

```html
function MainController($scope,$location) {
     $scope.myValue = false; 

}
```

and this is my body.

```
<body ng-controller="MainController as main">
    <div id="sradha" ng-show="myValue" >Show-side-bar</div>
    <div ui-view></div>

    <!--<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/ui-router/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/all.js"></script>
</body>
```

My problem is **Show-side-bar** is showing for 2 to 3 seconds when i am doing the refresh   ,then it hides .I have checked in console .It is hidden in the HTML.Here i want to show this **show-side-bar** when I am redirecting from login response (  $window.location.href = 'http://localhost/Angular-js-admin/admin/#/home';) to home page of my project

I have attached some screen shorts ,please have a look.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWnlz.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKzsh.png

Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried adding the attribute `ng-cloak` to the body? `<body ng-controller="MainController as main" ng-cloak>`

Comment: No i have tried @Filype

Comment: Try $apply, it might be problem of assignment before initialization.

Comment: try  $apply if not solved put this in controller    (function(){$scope.myValue = false; })()

Comment: I found the issue, this is due to initialization of different controllers. Sidebar gets initialized using maincontroller.myValue, and you are setting myValue of homecontroller which wouldn't work because it is not visible to the main controller template. So, the solution is either create a service for saving the value of myvalue variable or put it in rootscope. I think, first try putting it in rootscope.

Comment: Yes I put it in MainController ,its coming fine but i need to show it after login pages only . @Manish Singh

Comment: Yes, that's why rather setting this value in homecontroller, try putting it in $rootscope because homecontroller value wouldn't visible to maincontroller view.

Comment: where is that you are using home controller? !! **also you need the side bar to be hidden on the initial load or visible**

Comment: @sradha did you checked the answer ?

Comment: Yes I checked it  @Rohit Jindal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `controller as` syntax. So, the controller function we declare as usual, just using the `this` Object instead of `$scope`.

```
app.controller('MainController', function () {
    this.myValue = true;
});
```

This is more of a class based setup, and when instantiating a Controller in the `DOM` we get to instantiate against a `variable` :

// MainController doesn't exist, we get the `main` instance only

To reflect `this.myValue` based check in the `DOM`, we need to do this :

```
<div ng-controller="MainController as main">
    <div id="sradha" ng-show="main.myValue" >Show-side-bar</div>
</div>
```

## [Demo!](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitjindal/4zmtwb0v/)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ngStorage` to keep scope variable on page reload by using `$localStorage` in controller.

```
$scope.var1 = $localStorage.var1;
$scope.var2 = $localStorage.var2;
$scope.var3 = $localStorage.var3;
```

and in your function update `$localStorage` variables the same as `$scope` variables (assign) new values.

it works with me to keep div element shown using ng-show (depending on $scope variable) after page reload.

**Example:** to keep chat inbox opened after page reload without re-opening it.

we can find more on [github page](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage).